# Problem with nested left-joins and coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, coalesce

I have strange issue with nested left-joins in postgresql... It's hard to explain, but easy to show =) here we are:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 1 as key1
) sub1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT sub3.key3, sub4.value2 FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 as key3
    ) sub3
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT sub5.key5, COALESCE(sub6.value1, 1) as value2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 1 as key5
        ) sub5
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT 1 as key6, value1
            FROM
            (
                SELECT NULL::integer as value1
            ) sub7
            WHERE false
        ) sub6 ON false

    )
    sub4 ON sub4.key5=sub3.key3
)
sub2 ON sub1.key1 = sub2.key3
```

The result of this query:

```
key1;key3;value2
1;1;NULL
```

And this is the problem - value2 can't be NULL because of COALESCE in sub4 (at least I think that it can't be =))
Anyway if we'll change

```
SELECT sub3.key3, sub4.value2 FROM
```

with

```
SELECT sub3.key3, value2 FROM
```

we will got correct result:

```
key1;key3;value2
1;1;1
```

Is there something wrong with my mind&hands? or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to reproduce that if you are not posting the table definitions and the data in the tables.

Comment: @Peter: what table definitions? There are no tables.

Comment: @listar, that's a pretty crazy finding, even if your SQL is not exactly simple to understand. But I'd also expect `value2 = 1`. Have you tried expressing your `COALESCE` as a `CASE` expression?

Comment: @Peter: Lukas is right - there isn't any table definition =)

Comment: @Lukas: yes, I tried and the result is the same =( that why I asked my question here... if the problem was in coalesce, I would try to look in sources as I did before... but this is to difficult to investigate by source code =))PS and I'm sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from postgresql team.
Verdict:

```
This is on HEAD from today.  Clearly there's a problem.
```

So, it was (and it is) a bug. Thanks for all, who participated in this issue! =)

Answer (score 1):

I have translated your query to Oracle syntax and I get the expected result

```
+------+------+--------+
| KEY1 | KEY3 | VALUE2 |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    1 |      1 |
+------+------+--------+
```

resulting from

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 as key1 from dual
) sub1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sub3.key3, sub4.value2 FROM (
        SELECT 1 as key3 from dual
    ) sub3
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sub5.key5, COALESCE(sub6.value1, 1) as value2
        FROM (
            SELECT 1 as key5 from dual
        ) sub5
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 1 as key6, value1
            FROM (
                SELECT cast(NULL as NUMBER(7)) as value1 from dual
            ) sub7
            WHERE 1=0
        ) sub6 ON 1=0
    )
    sub4 ON sub4.key5 = sub3.key3
)
sub2 ON sub1.key1 = sub2.key3
```

Also, from reading this rather odd query, I still think that the result you get from Postgres is wrong. I think you can safely file this as a bug to Postgres

Comment: I guess the bug could be related to the "always false" condition, which might be interpreted too optimistically by the query execution optimiser...

Comment: maybe you are right =) but I think at the moment only source code investigation could shed some light on this, but, as I said before, I'm not ready for such investigation =)) I'll wait for reaction from postgresql team =)

Comment: I wouldn't look at that source code either. I imagine the depths of nested outer join query plan calculation reach the complexity of quantum physics ;-)

Comment: you are absolutely right!! =)) besides, quantum physics is a little bit more interesting I think =))